# chrome.storage.sync.get not returning complete JS object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension that allows users to easily login to an internal webpage. The extension would show a menu containing pre-defined credentials from which the user can pick one and immediately be logged into the corresponding web page.(think Bookmarks++).

As a first step, I wanted to write the functionality that accepts 'name', 'url', 'username' and 'password' information in the Extension Options page and persist that using **chrome.storage.sync.set**. The user can have multiple sets of such information persisted using chrome.storage (e.g different usernames for the same website). I am able to do this successfully and the options page is also able to list all the saved information. For the time being, please ignore the security issues associated with client-side password encryption.

This is my manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "My Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Easy login to My Webapp",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/Cloud16.png",
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "html/options.html",
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"]    
}
```

This is save handler in the options page (in options.js):

```
function saveHandler() {
    var name = $("#name").val(),
        url = $("#url").val(),
        password = $("#password").val(),
        key = Date.now() + "",   //key based on currentTimeInMillis
        obj = {
            "id": key,
            "name": name,
            "url": url,
            "password": password
        };
    chrome.storage.sync.get('LOGIN_COLLECTION', function(items) {
            //Create a new collection if not exists
        if(items && !items['LOGIN_COLLECTION']) {
            items['LOGIN_COLLECTION'] = {};         
        }
        items['LOGIN_COLLECTION'][obj.id] = obj;
        chrome.storage.sync.set(items, function() {
            // Notify that we saved.
            console.log('Settings saved');
            chrome.storage.sync.get('LOGIN_COLLECTION', function(data) {            
                console.dir(data);
            });
        });
        $("#addUrlDialog").slideUp();
        loadExistingInfo(); //Read persisted data, and show. This works fine!!
    });
}
```

When the user clicks on the extension icon in the toolbar, I show a popup html which has a script to fetch the data (using chrome.storage.get) that was persisted in the options page. The code to fetch data in the popup looks like this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('LOGIN_COLLECTION', function(items) {
    var container = $("#listContainer"),
    data = items['LOGIN_COLLECTION'];
    for(item in data) {          
        console.dir(item); //**Outputs empty object**
        $("<div></div>").text(item.name).appendTo(container);
    }
});
```

[image: Screenshot of the js console for popup page]

As you can see, the fetch is able to get only the top-level object information, but none of its attributes. Should I be using content scripts or background pages to read data set by chrome.storage.sync.set? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the for...in loop correctly. They key is iterated, not the values.

```
for(key in data) {
    var item = data[key];
    console.dir(item);
    $("<div></div>").text(item.name).appendTo(container);
}
```

Comment: It indeed was the key that was the problem. Fixing it makes the extension work. Thanks :)